# Images size issue in UpdateTexture

Tags: android, andengine

I'm Trying to update the TextureRegion for a sprite dynamically.Following [UpdateTextureExample](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/UpdateTextureExample.java?r=713c5a7cb558947c6653c2c6898bd6b573b3b1fe)

But the images that I have to replace with are different in size. Is there a work around for this??

The image replaced is stretched out, as the previous image was bigger in size!!

Comment: As per my consideration you can not use image of different size for update texture.

Comment: Ok, will try something else then. Thanks!